# The basic of functional derivative

Tags: derivatives

I've just started to learn mathematical physics, and I read [Stone and Goldbart's *Mathematics for Physics*](http://www.goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf). But right at the beginning when they introduce the functional derivative, I couldn't understand their explanation:

> **1.2.1. The functional derivative:**
>
> We restrict ourselves to expressions of the form
>
> $$J[y] = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f[ \, x, y, y',y'',...y^{(n)} ] \, dx $$
>
> Consider a functional $J=\int f dx$ in which f depends only on $x, y$ and $y'$. Make a change $y(x) \rightarrow y(x) + \epsilon \eta (x)$, where $\epsilon$ is a (small) $x$-independent constant. The resultant change in J is:
> $$\begin{align} J[y+\epsilon \eta]-J[y] &=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\{f(x,y+\epsilon \eta,y'+\epsilon \eta')-f(x,y,y')\}dx \\ &= \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \{\epsilon \eta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\epsilon\frac{d\eta}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}+O(\epsilon^2)\}\\ &= ......(\text{this part I understand})\end{align} $$

I can't really wrap my head around this. What is that $\eta(x)$ that suddenly showed up? How did they manage from the first line to the second line in the above expression? And why is there a big-O at the end? (If you don't have the book you can actually find on page 16 [right here](http://www.goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf), the next part is just an integration by part). I'm honestly clueless.

It'd be awesome if someone can explain this to me please?

Comment: "Make a change $y(x) \rightarrow y(x) + \epsilon \eta (x)$, where $\epsilon$ is a (small) $x$-indipendent constant." $\eta$ is just some random (well-behaved) function. And the big-O is because you are expanding in powers of $\epsilon$; it just means "some terms of order $\epsilon^2$".

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I think so. There is no physics involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\eta(x)$ is some random well-behaved function you add to $y$ (it is the "variation").

Now, for a single-variable function, you have ([Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series))

$$f(x+x_0) \simeq f(x) + x_0  \partial_x f(x_0)$$

For a function of three variables, we have

$$f(x+x_0,y+y_0,z+z_0) \simeq f(x,y,z)+x_0 \partial_xf(x_0,y_0,z_0)+y_0 \partial_yf(x_0,y_0,z_0)+z_0 \partial_zf(x_0,y_0,z_0)$$

Applying this result to your integrand, you obtain

$$f(x,y+\epsilon \eta, y'+\epsilon \eta') \simeq f(x,y,y')+\epsilon \eta \ \partial_y f (x,y,y')+ \epsilon \eta' \ \partial_{y'}f(x,y,y')$$

The other terms in the expansion contain multiplicative factors $\epsilon^2,\epsilon^3,\epsilon^4 \dots$, so we just write

$$f(x,y+\epsilon \eta, y'+\epsilon \eta') = f(x,y,y')+\epsilon \eta \ \partial_y f (x,y,y')+ \epsilon \eta' \ \partial_{y'}f(x,y,y')+O(\epsilon^2)$$

meaning that there is an additional part containin terms $t_k$ every one of which satisfies

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left| \frac{t_k}{\epsilon^2} \right| < \infty$$

Plugging this result in the integral, you obtain the final result.